# Interpreting Combined Address Fields using known list of correct data - Efficiency Question

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, oracle18c

One table contains:

```
ADDR varchar,
CONTACT varchar, 
REFER varchar,
TEMP_FK number
```

The Foreign Key and Type are our delineators for unique outputs, related to existing data relationships. Contact remains unchanged, and the Address column does not contain unique addresses.

The ADDR Column is the address column formatted as "1234 Main St Apt 12 City State ZIP-4ZIP" where '-4ZIP' is optional. This is the main problem we're dealing with. We want to parse this into it's components, formatted as:

```
Line1: "1234 Main St"
Line2: "Apt 12"
City: "City"
State "State Abbreviation"
ZIP: "5ZIP"
```

I've assembled 2 other tables provided by USPS, one containing every City / State / Zip Code combination, and the other for every Street Delineation used in the Unites States (eg. Street, St, Place, Pl, etc).

For this question, we're only dealing with the first table of City / State / ZipCode combinations.

Thankfully this process needs to happen just once and going forward the data should be in this new format. So far I've come up with the following for Cleaning up everything but Lines 1&2:

```
select *
from(
select  substr(ADDR, 1, instr(ADDR, ZP.CITY)-1) as LINES_1_2,
        CONTACT,
        ZP.CITY,
        ZP.ST,
        ZP.ZIP,
        ADDR,
        row_number() over (partition by ADDR order by ZP.CITY DESC) as ADD_UNIQ,
        row_number() over (partition by TEMP_FK || REFER order by TEMP_FK DESC) as KEY_UNIQ,
        TEMP_FK,
        REFER
from address_temp
cross apply(
    select  physical_city as CITY,
            physical_state_abv as ST,
            physical_zip as ZIP
            from ZIP_USPS
            where   ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_CITY ||  '%')
            AND (ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_STATE_ABV || '%')
            OR ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_STATE || '%'))
            AND ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_ZIP || '%')
)ZP
)
where KEY_UNIQ = 1
```

KEY_UNIQ Solves the Duplicating Rows issue, as the ZIP_USPS table has the same City, State, Zip Fields multiple times, as that table is unique based upon the last 4 of a Zip, eg XXXXX-XXXX. The last 4 of the ZIP is its own Column. ADD_UNIQ I was using to group addresses, and obtain a value for uniqueness, for later interpolating that we'll be doing.

My first iteration of this was using **inner join** instead of **Cross Apply**, but **Cross Apply** is faster. I'm assuming all of my lost time (creating a sample of 40 rows processes in around 80s) is from my **where** clause with all the wild cards and variable matches it has to check for (the ZIP_USPS table has 44045 rows). I thought of using **distinct**, on my cross apply, but it is around 0.66s slower when I did it that way. That statement was:

```
select  substr(ADDR, 1, instr(ADDR, ZP.CITY)-1) as LINES_1_2,
        CONTACT,
        ZP.CITY,
        ZP.ST,
        ZP.ZIP,
        ADDR,
        TEMP_FK,
        REFER
from address_temp
cross apply(
    select distinct  physical_city as CITY,
            physical_state_abv as ST,
            physical_zip as ZIP
            from ZIP_USPS
            where   ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_CITY ||  '%')
            AND (ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_STATE_ABV || '%')
            OR ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_STATE || '%'))
            AND ADDR LIKE ('%' || ZIP_USPS.PHYSICAL_ZIP || '%')
)ZP
```

My data sample is not clean enough to fully just search by ZIP for my output, and I'd be worried about those few occasions where ZIPs overlap cities in larger metropolitan areas.

My main question here is efficiency. I think I'm doing something wrong, but can't really see a better way to do it.

What improvements could / should I make here?

Sample Data:

| ADDR | CONTACT | REFER | TEMP_FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 MAIN ST HAMPDEN MA 01036 | 156 | final | 200 |
| 1 WILLIAMS ST WILLIAMSBURG MA 01096 | 100 | final | 3000 |
| 650 DWIGHT ST HOLYOKE MA 01040 | 95 | inv | 3500 |
| 650 DWIGHT ST HOLYOKE MA 01040 | 95 | final | 3500 |
| 83 WINSOR ST LUDLOW MA 01056 | 300 | inv | 2333 |
| 40 POST OFFICE PARK WILBRAHAM MA 01095 | 250 | inv | 3333 |

Sample Output:

| LINES_1_2 | CITY | ST | ZIP | ADDR | CONTACT | REFER | TEMP_FK | ADD_UNIQ | KEY_UNIQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 MAIN ST | HAMPDEN | MA | 01036 | 534 MAIN ST HAMPDEN MA 01036 | 156 | final | 200 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 WILLIAMS ST | WILLIAMSBURG | MA | 01096 | 1 WILLIAMS ST WILLIAMSBURG MA 01096 | 100 | final | 3000 | 1 | 1 |
| 650 DWIGHT ST | HOLYOKE | MA | 01040 | 650 DWIGHT ST HOLYOKE MA 01040 | 95 | inv | 3500 | 1 | 1 |
| 650 DWIGHT ST | HOLYOKE | MA | 01040 | 650 DWIGHT ST HOLYOKE MA 01040 | 95 | final | 3501 | 2 | 1 |
| 83 WINSOR ST | LUDLOW | MA | 01056 | 83 WINSOR ST LUDLOW MA 01056 | 300 | inv | 2333 | 1 | 1 |
| 40 POST OFFICE PARK | WILBRAHAM | MA | 01095 | 40 POST OFFICE PARK WILBRAHAM MA 01095 | 250 | inv | 3333 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: I can think of two improvements, but I'm not sure if they are actually possible in your case. First, try to remove those leading `%` in your queries; maybe you can do some pre-parsing and extract the city in advance in order to compare using `=`  or using `LIKE city || '%'`. Second, you can decompose that `OR` using two separate `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: A totally different fast solution is to use Full Text Search. I don't know if it's sold separately in Oracle, but it's free in PostgreSQL and it can be blazing fast when used correctly.

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data (enough to illustrate the different data scenarios) and the output you want to achieve based on that data? Thanks

Comment: @NickW When I tried to add sample data, Stack overflow said "This looks like spam" and didn't let me post unfortunately. I'll try to edit in an example at the end, and see if it bypasses the filter

Comment: @TheImpaler The query to extract the City ahead of time is the same amount of time as the more expansive query suprisingly. I did get some bad matches as well. Though your comment did make me realize I don't NEED to look for the state at all (the `OR` clause was there to look for "New York" or "NY"). I just need City and ZIP to get the correct data match. I'm down 1.7s on the query now.

Comment: @KXross Awesome. Lateral thinking is a great thing.